# When do you use the o marker with kudasai (Please)

Tags: grammar, particle-を

Here are some Japanese sentences:

> Aisu-kōhī-o kudasai (Please give me iced coffee)
>   Mizu-o kudasai (Please give me water)
>   Kippu kudasai (Please give me a ticket)

Why doesn't the last sentence use the `o` marker? Is it a misprint or is there a rule to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the last sentence is a misprint.

Case markers play the crucially important roles to indicate the relationship of the preceding nouns to the verb of a sentence or a clause. However, they could be omitted when it is easy to assume the meaning of a sentence from the vocabularies.

Comment: I do not know why the last sentence should be considered to be a misprint, given what you wrote in the second paragraph.

Comment: @nomithekid @Tsuyoshi Ito - Would you drop the `o` to be more casual. E.g. like how in English `do not` is shortened to `don't`

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito I thought the sentences were from the textbook. If it's from the textbook, it is a misprint because case particles are given weight in teaching Japanese as a second language. If it's not from the textbook, it is not a misprint.

Comment: @big_smile In conversation, yes. Although, I would suggest you to keep using it if you are at the beginner level. Japanese particles are not easy to distinguish the functions.

Comment: Perfect, just in case anyone encounters this, the book was `Learn Japanese in your car`.

Comment: nomithekid: You are basically saying, “You can omit を and say きっぷください in spoken Japanese in the real world, but because a textbook cannot show the real language, it must be a misprint if it appears in a textbook.” I do not know where your belief comes from.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito If it's not a misprint and for the beginners without explaining why and when Japanese omit some particles, I'd think the authors needed more consideration to make a textbook. That's how case particles are usually not omitted in the textbook unless they only focus on 'spoken casual Japanese'. If my belief is wrong, please give a better answer to OP. I'm here to be a help for OP but to argue with someone.